# SQL Query for Archival Table with Multiple As of Dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a query to return data from an archival table from multiple as of dates. I know how to return data for a single point in time:

```
declare @Date date = '2023-09-01'; 
declare @DateTime DATETIME = concat(@Date,' 10:30:00.000');

select 
    @Date,
    [Item],
    [Quantity]
from 
    Fruit for SYSTEM_TIME as of @DateTime;
```

I have the first day of the month in its own `FirstDateMonth` table that looks like this:

| Date | DateTimeUTC |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-01 10:30:00.000 |
| 2023-02-01 | 2023-02-01 10:30:00.000 |
| 2023-03-01 | 2023-03-01 10:30:00.000 |
| 2023-04-01 | 2023-04-01 10:30:00.000 |
| 2023-05-01 | 2023-05-01 10:30:00.000 |
| 2023-06-01 | 2023-06-01 10:30:00.000 |
| 2023-07-01 | 2023-07-01 10:30:00.000 |
| 2023-08-01 | 2023-08-01 10:30:00.000 |
| 2023-09-01 | 2023-09-01 10:30:00.000 |

I want to write a query like the one above, but that loops through each date on the `FirstDateMonth` table and returns results similar to this:

| Date | Item | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | Apple | 2 |
| 2023-01-01 | Banana | 4 |
| 2023-02-01 | Apple | 2 |
| 2023-02-01 | Banana | 5 |
| 2023-03-01 | Apple | 3 |
| 2023-03-01 | Banana | 1 |
| 2023-04-01 | Apple | 8 |
| 2023-04-01 | Banana | 1 |
| 2023-05-01 | Apple | 4 |
| 2023-05-01 | Banana | 3 |
| etc... |  |  |

Any suggestions on how to make this happen?

Comment: Do you mean temporal tables? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16 (you probably want `contained in` or `all` from that manual page, then a join on your dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from memory as I don't have anything to test with at the moment..

The basic principle is to create a table valued function that returns data for a single point in time and the cross apply that to your start of month dates.

It's something like

```
CREATE FUNCTION getFruitAsOf (@AsOdDate datetime)
    RETURNS TABLE 
    AS 
        (SELECT * FROM dbo.Fruit FRO SYSTEM_TIME AS OF @AsOfDate)
```

Then cross apply this to your dates table

```
SELECT 
    d.StartDateTime, 
    f.*
FROM myDatesTable d 
    CROSS APPLY getFruitAsOf(d.StartDateTime) f
```